# what objects can be released immediately after adding to self.view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In a test program, I init 2 UITextFields, 2 UILabels, 1 UITextView and 1 UIButton programmatically in (void)loadview, and I try to release them immediately after [self.view addSubview:controlname] at the last of loadview. All of them work ok except UIButton. So when should I release button? And I wanna know what objects can be released immediately added to self.view?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are creating the button with UIButton's +(id)buttonWithType: and if that is the case, you shouldn't release it.

I also would recommend using ARC so that you don't have to worry about this at all.

Comment: I'm starting learning iOS developing and the book always recommend not using ARC.

Comment: I'm not really sure why the book would recommend not using ARC since there are a lot more pros to using it than there are cons.

Answer (score 0):

Well, to release or not to release depends on if you own the object or not, and this depends on how you are creating your objects, From the [Memory Management Policy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html):

**You own any object you create**:
    You create an object using a method whose name begins with “alloc”, “new”, “copy”, or “mutableCopy” (for example, alloc, newObject, or mutableCopy).

Thus, if you created the object with some other method (one that doesn't start with these words) then you should not release it, since you don't own it.